# Comparative adverb

Tags: expressions, adverbs, comparatives, comparisons, adverb-position

I was taught that object of a preposition is always a noun, but I have often seen that a comparison adverb comes immediately after a preposition, then a noun phrase preceded by an adverb comes, which is beyond my grammar.

Note: Please don't tell me its meaning, I know it very well, rather it is all about grammar.

> He has been here for more than 2 years.

After "for" *more than* comes immediately, which is an adverb and is modifying the noun somehow.

Could anyone tell me what is the function of *more than* here and are they two combined words or separate?
If they are separate, what are they doing individually in a gramatical sense?

> Just like that, schedule me for as soon as possible.

Here again we have comparative adverb after "for".

Comment: Grammatically, *more than 2 years* is the same object of the preposition *for* as *years* would be: "Been here for years." So the noun is expanded to a noun phrase. Also, is "more than" an adverb? Longer than a year, redder than red, all sound like adjectives to me.

Comment: The actual rule is "The object of a preposition must be a noun phrase". Prepositional phrases, participles, and whole clauses can function as noun phrases. In _Bill thinks that the answer is wrong_, the direct object of the verb _thinks_ is the noun phrase consisting of the entire clause _that the answer is wrong_; the _that_ is there to intrroduce the clause and mark it as a noun phrase so it can be the object.

Comment: The complements of prepositions like "for" can belong to several subtypes. In those cases where the complement is an NP, we typically refer to it as the object of the prep, but in other cases we refer to its function as simply complement.  In your first example "for" has the NP "more than 2 years" as object in which "years" is head and "more than 2" is functioning as determiner. In your second example, "for" has the phrase "as soon as possible" as complement in which "as soon as" is a prepositional idiom.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin I'm with Solt [[CUNY; Complex Quantifiers Based on Many and Few](https://www.leibniz-zas.de/fileadmin/Archiv2019/mitarbeiter/solt/Solt_-_Extended_Abstract.pdf)] here in considering 'more than [numeral]' a **complex quantifier**. {2d}: '[More than {/over}100/fewer than 100] students attended the lecture' cf [Many/some/several ... / Oodles of ... ] students ... //// Solt makes the assumption '_more_ is taken to be the spell-out of _many+er_'.